# Nested Set Model or any kind of Hierarchical model in Entity Framework 4.2

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, nested-sets

I would like to know if there is some kind of plugin to manage nested set db design in entity framework 4.2

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

I have hierarchical data to deal with, and in my mind, Nested set is the more effective way to work with. 
I Know that there is something in Php Doctrine(ORM) and Hope there is something similar in EF.

Thanks.

Comment: Any idea, I just want to know if there is an already nuget package or something that I can use for Hierarchic data.